# Table-valued parameters in SpringBoot/Spring JPA

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I have stored procedure written in SQL Server which accepts a list of objects as input.

```
create procedure dbo.stageDealFile
    @fileName varchar(100), 
    @id int, 
    @arg1 dbo.dealFileAttrList readonly, 
    @arg2 dbo.dealFileAttrList readonly, 
    @arg3 dbo.dealFileAttrList readonly,
    @errorFlg bit output,
    @errorMessage nvarchar(100) output
as
begin
....
...

CREATE TYPE dbo.dealFileAttrList AS TABLE 
(
    maId      int           NOT NULL,
    attrName  nvarchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    attrValue nvarchar(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL
)
```

I am not sure that how to convert list of java object to `Array/Object[]`  which can be passed as input to Stored Procedure. I tried below options

1) Wrote class which extends StoredProcedure(Spring) and tried to pass as list(Assumed that Spring will take care of conversion), but NO luck

2) Tried simpleJdbcCall with below conversion logic, No luck on this as well, it throws error on conversion

```
Connection connection = simpleJdbcCallObj.getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection();
Array arg1StructArray = connection.createArrayOf("dbo.dealFileAttrList", arg1.toArray());
Array arg2StructArray = connection.createArrayOf("dbo.dealFileAttrList", arg2.toArray());
Array arg3StructArray = connection.createArrayOf("dbo.dealFileAttrList", arg3.toArray());
```

Exception:

> ```
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This operation is not supported.
>   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:234)
>   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.throwNotSupportedException(SQLServerException.java:412)
> ```

Comment: Something like [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/wiki/Using-TVP-with-stored-procedure-in-Spring-framework)?

Comment: Please post the entire stacktrace